# Complex Contour Integration using Magnitude and triangle inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have some questions and I have been asked to use the magnitude and triangle inequality. Here is the first question:

Let $C$ be the arc of the circle $|z| = 2$ from $z = 2i$ to $z = 2$, Show that
$$\left|\int_C\frac{dz}{z^2-1}\right|\leq\frac{\pi}{3}$$
I'm given this magnitude inequality to be the following theorem:

If on a contour $C$, $|f(z)|\leq M$ and $L$ is the length of $C$, then
$$\left|\int_Cf(z)\,dz\right|\leq\int_C|f(z)||dz|\leq ML$$
I would like to have a clear process for this question so I can attempt the few after it on my own. I just don't see what I should be looking for. What to do first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

$$\left|\int_C f(z)\,dz\right|\le \int_C |f(z)|\,|dz|$$

And $|z_1+z_2|\ge ||z_1|-|z_2||$.

Comment: So would it be true to say:
$$|z^2+(-1)|\geq ||z|^2 - |-1|| = |2^2 -1|$$

$$\Rightarrow |f(z)| = \left|\frac{1}{z^2 -1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{3}.\quad L = \pi d = \frac{4\pi}{4} = \pi.$$

$$\Rightarrow \left|\int_C\frac{dz}{z^2 -1}\right|\leq ML = \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Comment: Yes, well done!  You have it now.

Comment: Although, $L\ne \pi d$ here.  Rather, it is $\frac14 \pi d=\frac14\times \pi\times  4=\pi$.  Is that what your calculation was?

Comment: Oh yes. I saw the circumference of a circle is $\pi d$ and the contour is a quarter of that so I'll be more accurate and say $L = \frac{1}{4}\pi d$ But thank you! I wasn't sure about the triangle inequality part but this has helped a lot!

Comment: You're quite welcome.  My pleasure and very pleased to see that you really understand it well.  -Mark